# Saber si una fecha está entre dos fechas en php

Tags: php

Lo tengo hecho manualmente ahora pero me ocupa mucho código. He estado investigando y al parecer antes se podía usar `check_in_range()`, pero por lo visto ya no funciona. Ni siquiera aparece en la documentación de PHP.

¿Hay alguna forma de comprobar si una fecha, está entre otras dos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me consta que tal función haya existido por defecto en PHP y si existió y la quitaron debe ser algo *curioso*, como lo es que no exista algo similar en el core de PHP.

Pero puedes incluirla entre tus funciones personalizadas:

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/XWGHO19906)

```
<?php


/* Función */
function check_in_range($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin, $fecha){

     $fecha_inicio = strtotime($fecha_inicio);
     $fecha_fin = strtotime($fecha_fin);
     $fecha = strtotime($fecha);

     if(($fecha >= $fecha_inicio) && ($fecha <= $fecha_fin)) {

         return true;

     } else {

         return false;

     }
 }


/*Código de prueba*/

$fecha_inicio = '2017-08-15'; 
$fecha_fin = '2017-08-31';
$fecha = '2017-08-22';

if (check_in_range($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin, $fecha))
{

    echo "$fecha está en el rango\n";

} else {

    echo "$fecha NO está en el rango\n";

}


$fecha_inicio = '2017-08-15'; 
$fecha_fin = '2017-08-31';
$fecha = '2018-08-22';

if (check_in_range($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin, $fecha))
{
    echo "$fecha está en el rango\n";

} else {

    echo "$fecha NO está en el rango\n";

}

?>
```

#### `Resultado`:

```
2017-08-22 está en el rango
2018-08-22 NO está en el rango
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes convertirlas en timestamps y compararlas

```
$fecha1 = strtotime($fecha1);
$fecha2 = strtotime($fecha2);
$fechaComprobar = strtotime($fechaComprobar);

if ($fechaComprobar >= $fecha1) && ($fechaComprobar <= $fecha2){
    return true;
}
else{
    false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tal vez puedas usar la función [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) ya que recibe un parámetro de tipo cadena  y regresa un timestamps que es un valor entero, con eso puedes resolver el problema de forma muy sencilla.

```js
$date1 = "2017-08-17";
$date2 = "2017-07-17";
$date3 = "2017-07-25";

function date_in_range($date1, $date2, $date3) {
 $number1 = strtotime($date1);
 $number2 = strtotime($date2);
 $number3 = strtotime($date3);
 if (($number1 >= $number3) && ($number2 <= $number3)) {
  return 1;
 }
 return 0;
}
```